# Generation of kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning algebra and I am not sure if I understood the definition of a kernel of a group homomorphism correctly.

Let $G$ be a group generated by $S=\{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$ and $H$ any group. I have a group homomorphism $f: G \to H$.

The kernel of a group homomorphism if defined by $ker(f)=\{g \in G \mid f(g)=e\}$.

Doese this mean that $\ker(f)$ if generated by all $s_i \in S$ with $f(s_i)=e$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(s_1)=-f(s_2)$, then $f(s_1+s_2)=e$ and so $s_1+s_2\in\text{Ker}(f)$, but neither $s_1$ nor $s_2$ lies in the kernel.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of generators : $ F = (a_i)_{1 \leq i \leq k} \in S^k$ where $S$ is a group then in general you can’t always find  a subset : $V_H \subset F$ such that $H = < V_H>$ (where $H$ is a subgroup of $S$.

For example take the cyclic group : $S = \mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have : $S = < F > = <\bar 1>$, but it is impossible to find a subset $V$ of $F$ such that the subgroup : $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $V$.

So for example just take the homomorphism : $f:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} /4 \mathbb{Z}$ defined by : $f(0) = f(2) = 0, f(1) =f(3) = 1$.
We then have : $\ker f = \mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z}$, and this as I said a counter example to your assumption.